# Converting multiple date formats in a column to a single form

Tags: r, date

I have a column within a dataframe that contains date information that is stored in multiple forms e.g.

```
dob <- c("18/02/1983","36782","01/11,1999 11:55",
         "Dead 12/12/2001","Alive 03/07/1985")
```

I'd like to convert all of these into `POSIXlt` dates of the format `"%d/%m/%Y"`, with no time info, and no `"Dead"` or `"Alive"` prefixing them.

All previous solutions to similar problems involve only two possible formats, that I can tell, whereas I have more, and also I have the problem of converting the 5 digit number format dates (which I think are numeric dates with origin 1970-01-01 from Excel) also.  I'm using R-3.1.2. Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: You need to understand your source data, because some of the dates will be ambiguous.  For example, is `"01/11,1999"` November 1, 1999; or January 11, 1999?

Comment: Your Excel dates might be a problem (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15686451/489704))

Comment: They are all %d/%m/%Y, luckily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy or simple solution for this, you'll have to at least go through the formats by hand. But saying that, the pseudocode for solution would be something like this:

```
tmp <- grepl('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', dob))
formats[tmp] <- '%d/%m/%Y'
tmp <- grepl( other format, dob)
formats[tmp] <- 'other format'
etc...
dates <- strptime(dob, formats)
```

Answer (score 5):

`lubridate` is flexible as far as date formatting is concerned.

Depending on how representative your sample of 5 dates is of your larger dataset, you could parse them once to filter out those that are generally day-month-year. Then, assuming the remainder are the dodgy Excel dates, parse them separately according to their proper origin (word of warning, this might [depend on which OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15686451/489704) the Excel file was created on).

```
library(lubridate)
d <- parse_date_time(dob, c('%d%m%y', '%d%m%y %H%M'))
d[is.na(d)] <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(dob[is.na(d)]), 
                                  origin = "1899-12-30"))

d

## [1] "1983-02-18 00:00:00 UTC" "2000-09-13 00:00:00 UTC" "1999-11-01 11:55:00 UTC"
## [4] "2001-12-12 00:00:00 UTC" "1985-07-03 00:00:00 UTC"
```

AFAIK you can't omit time info from `POSIXlt`/`POSIXct` objects, so if you want to do that you might need to:

```
as.Date(d)
```

which will be in `%d-%m-%Y`format (in my locale),

or

```
format(d, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

which will be `character`.